# Meaning of the term fouler in a noun form other than as an adjective

Tags: word-usage, usage

Does English language recognise the term fouler as one who commits foul/s other than just an adjective like 'fouler deeds' etc?I have seen foul being used as a verb as in railways such as 'fouling area' where cars are allowed to derail etc.We also say that he fouled up the situation,but I have not heard persons calling someone a fouler.

Comment: Since _foul_ is a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foul), and in English (almost) every verb can be nouned (and vice versa), _fouler_ can be a [noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fouler). That said, I can't say I've seen it being used like that very often, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

We can generate one-who-does nouns (ending in **-er**) from verbs on an ad hoc basis.  Watching a basketball game on TV with friends, say, we might be distracted for a moment when someone comes in the door to join the party, and upon returning, we see a player standing at the free-throw line.  We *could* ask, **Who was the fouler?** although we'd probably say **Who fouled him?**

Answer (score 0):

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/foul?s=t) doesn't supply 'fouler' as a word. That isn't to say that it is never used, as language does change, but I have never heard it used as a noun to describe a person in the way you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

GloWbE has 20 matches for "fouler" as a noun; but half of them are wrongly classified. I count seven of them that are clearly nouns: six of these are derived from "foul" in the sporting sense. The seventh appears to be a bird-catcher, but evidently a quotation in archaic spelling. There are also two very similar quotes from New Zealand that I can't make much sense of, but they appear to be something in fashion: but they might be comparative adjectives used in a rather odd syntax.